# Using PHP to manage(add/edit/update) Trac via XML-RPC - Sample code/Tutorial?

Tags: php, trac, xml-rpc

I know there exists xml-rpc plugin for Trac (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin), but I was wondering if anybody knows any example/tutorial for using xml-rpc PHP client to update Trac infos.

Thanks

Comment: I found a very good article on PHP XML-RPC @ http://devzone.zend.com/article/1307, but not specifically targeted for Trac Project though. But that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I used XmlRpc, I used [Zend_XmlRpc_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html). Here is one of the examples translated from Python to PHP (using `Zend_XmlRpc_Client`):

The trac runs on `localhost`:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php';

$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client("http://user:pass@localhost/login/xmlrpc");
$trac   = $client->getProxy();
echo $trac->getPage('WikiStart');
echo $trac->getPageHTML('WikiStart');
```

Does that get you started?